# checking filename

Tags: c#, filenames

How can i check if filename contains some string? for example if "frody" contains "ro"? 
I tried like that:

```
                    if (file_name.Contains("ro")== true)
```

and:

```
                       if (file_name.Contains("ro"))
```

Comment: Where is file_name coming from?  Are you using System.IO?

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. The second is probably more favoured.

E.g., this returns true:

```
string s = "test-ro.doc";
Console.WriteLine(s.Contains("ro"));
```

Comment: Watch out for a NullPointerException on file_name though.

Comment: I would also suggest to ignore case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (s == null || s.Trim().Length == 0) 
{ 
   return false 
} 
else 
{ 
   return s.ToLower().Contains("ro");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another problem. Thanks for help.